# Selenium python: simulate file drag

Tags: jquery, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

how can I simulate the action of dragging and dropping *a file* from the filesystem to an element that has a ondrag event trigger?

As for the normale "file" input, I was able to set the value of the input with jQuery. Can't I create a javascript File object or use any similar hack?

Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is a commercial wrapper around Selenium called [Helium](http://heliumhq.com) that lets you do what you want in one command:

```
drag_file('/path/to/file.txt', to=driver.find_element_by_id("yourElement"))
```

(I am affiliated with Helium.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's a matter of either sending the filepath to the input, because I think that's all dragging the file around really does, or use a created element with JS and use [drag_and_drop_by_offset](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.click_and_hold) with move to element.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium only works with your web browser. If you are opening something other than a web browser such as file browser you cannot interact with it. Drag and drops work with items within a web browser but not from program such as Windows Explorer or a Linux file explorer to a web browser. Create and element in your browser with jQuery and drag and drop it.

Comment: Hi, what object can I create that generates an event with a files that can be used by FileReader.readAsDataURL? This is what dragging a file from the filesystem does and also what I do need. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something like this

```
query = '''function previewFile() {
          var preview = document.querySelector('img');
          var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
          var reader  = new FileReader();

          reader.onloadend = function () {
            preview.src = reader.result;
          }

          if (file) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          } else {
            preview.src = "";
          }
        }'''

driver.execute_script(query)
```

You will have to play around with the details but this should read your file and you may have to send it to somewhere in your DOM.